# Replace location url on browser history back in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, browser-history

I want to use $location.replace() on a history back event (user clicks on browsers back button). Putting $location.replace() in $routeChangeStart doesn't seem to work, because location change is already completed i think.

Can this be only done by manipulating the history api myself?